# ¿cómo saber cuanto tiempo a pasado de una hora a otra en formato 24hr?

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, time

estoy haciendo una función en JavaScript para calcular cuanto debe pagar el usuario depende el tiempo que haya usado el servicio.

ahora bien, el calculo de cuanto tiempo a pasado ya está listo y corre bien **pero** solo cuando el tiempo de salida es el mayor osea en éstos casos no hay problema`entrada = 12:45 salida = 15:25` allí el tiempo que ha pasado es de `2:40` , perfecto, pero si la cosa es al revés salen cálculos errados ya que es como si hubiera usado el servicio de un día [12,45],[3,40] para otro.

ésta es mi función en javascript:

```
function _calculatePrice(start,end){//start[hour,minutes] end[hour,minutes]
    let begin = start[0]*60 + start[1], // hour * 60 + minutes = all the time in minutes
    final = end[0]*60 + end[1],
    transcurred = final - begin, //total time transcurred in minutes
    hour = 0;

    for(transcurred; transcurred >= 60 ; transcurred -= 60){
        hour++;
    }
    return hour.toString() + ':' + transcurred.toString()
}

let time = _calculatePrice([12,45],[15,25])
console.log(time)//"2:40" todo bien
```

pero si hago
    `_calculatePrice([12,45],[3,40])
// sale "0:-545"`

y claro es que la lógica de la funcion no está preparada para eso, pero **he allí mi problema** , no le he encontrado la lógica para ese caso me imagino que tal vez deba tomar cada tiempo como un día aparte osea , en el caso de `[12,45] y [3,40]` calcular cuanto a pasado desde las 12:45 hasta las 23:59 y luego calcular desde las 00:00 hasta las 3:40 y sumar eso

pero mientras pienso en ello si alguien tiene otra manera de resolverlo es totalmente bienvenido, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el tiempo transcurrido es menor de cero, restalo a 24h.

```
function _calculatePrice(start,end){//start[hour,minutes] end[hour,minutes]
        let begin = start[0]*60 + start[1], // hour * 60 + minutes = all the time in minutes
        final = end[0]*60 + end[1],
        transcurred = final - begin, //total time transcurred in minutes
        if (transcurred <0) {transcurred = (24*60)+transcurred;}
        hour = 0;

        for(transcurred; transcurred >= 60 ; transcurred -= 60){
            hour++;
        }
        return hour.toString() + ':' + transcurred.toString()
    }
```

Comment: tienes razón carmen, no había pensado en eso, de la manera que yo decia que era tomar cada valor como un día aparte y luego sumar ambos resultados también sirve pero tu solución es más corta e igual de efectiva, gracias

Answer (score 1):

ésta es otra solución pero un poco más larga, dejo los 2 ejemplos, el de arriba por parte de @Carmen y el mio, el primero es mejor pero ésta también es otra solución, yo usaré el primero, el segundo solo es un poquito más legible pero más largo

aqui el ejemplo

```
function _calculatePrice(start,end){//start[hour,minutes] end[hour,minutes]
    let begin = start[0]*60 + start[1], // hour * 60 + minutes = all the time in minutes
    final = end[0]*60 + end[1],
    transcurred = final - begin, //total time transcurred in minutes
    hour = 0;
    //FIRST SOLUTION
    // ====== short solution ======
    //if(transcurred < 0) transcurred += 24 * 60;
    //===========   ***   ===========

    //SECOND SOLUTION
    // large solution =================
    if(final < begin){
        let day1 = start[0]*60 + start[1];
        day1 = (23*60)+59 - (day1) + 1;//the end of the day 23:59 minus the day1 plus 1 minute
        let day2 =  end[0]*60 + end[1];

        transcurred = day1 + day2;
    }
    // ================================

    for(transcurred; transcurred >= 60 ; transcurred -= 60){
        hour++;
    }
    return hour.toString() + ':' + transcurred.toString()
}
```

Comment: Siempre es bueno tener soluciones alternativas